# How to: python script + imagemagic = windows application?

Tags: python, windows, tiles

I have a small problem. I have a script in python, which uses imagemagic. It works fine on my Mac, or Linux. But I need to give it to the client, and he uses Windows. Actually the question: how can I build applications for it, and on what to do Gui. (Perhaps you know the finished product is open source, who knows how to resize images and cut them into pieces 'tile cutter')

Answer (score 0):

You can use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to build application for it, may be you can bundle imagemagic with your app too.